# Opencart Product Image Not Visible in Chrome Using Journal Theme?

Tags: image, google-chrome, opencart, product, journal

Can Any One advice on 'Opencart Product Image Not Visible in Chrome Using Journal Theme' Opencart version 1.5.6.4 and Journal 2.2.1.

Comment: Product page image not visible all other images are visible

Comment: Its working in Mozilla, Explorer and in Mobile Chrome Not in the Desktop and Laptop

Answer (score 3):

put

```
.product-info .left .image * {
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

in your custom css tab (journal admin panel)

Comment: yes this css works fine. (i do not understand why this question is downvoted.)